# Probability with two IID random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, iid

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are two IID random variables with *infinite* support, I am interested in $P(X>a , X>Y+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are two constants. Is there any family of distribution for X and Y where this probability has a close-form solution? I am a simple solution without integrals.
I tried Normal and Gumbel Distributions with no success. In both cases, $P(X>Y+b)$ is relatively simple, especially in Gumbel case, but not $P(X>a , X>Y+b)$.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but the uniform distribution satisfies your requirements. Whether or not that helps you depends on whether you’re trying to prove non-existence or you’re actually trying to do meaningful modeling.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add that I am looking for a distribution with infinite support, just added that, I am really sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you regard as as a family and as a closed form.

For example if $X,Y \sim U(0,k)$ and $0 < b < a< k$ then $$P(X>a,X>Y+b) = \frac { (k-b)^2}{2k^2} -\frac { (a-b)^2}{2k^2} = \frac{(k-a)(k+a-2b)}{2k^2}$$  as should be clear from

[image]

Comment: I agree with you completely. I am looking for a family in the non-precise way, e.g. normal or exponential. And the ones interesting here are the ones with infinite support. I had forgot to add that, terribly sorry

Comment: btw, a very beautiful graph, which software do you use?

Comment: @AnonA Microsoft Paint